# Using crawler in nodeJS is not giving me any result but when I am trying same code in browser it gives. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

I'm using crawler in nodeJS as following

```
var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    callback : function (error, result, $) {}
});

c.queue([{
    uri: 'https://in.linkedin.com/nhome',
    jQuery: true,
    callback: function (error, result,$) {
        var str=[];
        $("#directory>.primary>li:not(.country-search)>a",result.body).each(function(){
            var tmpp=$(this).attr("href");
            str.push(tmpp);
        });
        console.log(str.length);     
    }
]);
```

returns 0

But if I go to "https://in.linkedin.com/nhome/" and in firebug I try following code

```
var str=[];
        $("#directory>.primary>li:not(.country-search)>a").each(function(){
            var tmpp=$(this).attr("href");
            str.push(tmpp);
        });
        console.log(str.length);
```

it works fine and returns 27.

where I'm doing wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with uri

The link https://in.linkedin.com/nhome
was wrong the right uri was https://in.linkedin.com/nhome/

without "/" it was redirecting to some another page where my scrapping code was not working.